# Attributes Missing - Parsing XML with SimpleXMLElement -

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Hello I'm having an issue parsing XML that I just can't seem to figure out.  Here is a snippet of what I get when I dump the variable the contains the raw XML output:

```
<hcAmount currencyCode="USD" decimals="2">180</hcAmount>
```

However, when I run`$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($curlResponse);` I'm not getting the attributes (specifically currencyCode and decimals in this case.  Here's a snippet of the hcAmount element:

```
 ["hcCharges"]=>
          object(SimpleXMLElement)#452 (2) {
            ["hcDescription"]=>
            string(9) "BASE RATE"
            ["hcAmount"]=>
            string(3) "180"
          }
```

It is missing the currencyCode and decimals attributes and I'm trying to sort out what I'm doing wrong to have those get dropped.  Thank you!

Comment: Do not rely on `print_r` or `var_dump` output of SimpleXMLElements as it's just a summary of the information.  If you want to see the actual content, use `->asXML()`

Comment: What exactly is your expected output from the sample xml?

Comment: @JackFleeting I'd like to be able to get the currencyCode value so I was expecting `[@attributes][currencyCode]` to appear in the array....

Comment: It's still not clear: the xml sample in your question has a few properties: it's a single node with a name (`hcAmount`),  two attributes: `currencyCode` with an attribute value of `"USD"` and `decimals` with an attribute value of `"2"`, and a text child node - `180`. Nothing else. So which of these do you want to output?

Comment: @JackFleeting I'd like to output currency code.....but that's where I'm confused.  That attribute is there on the raw XML but not when I run it through SimpleXMLElement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common confusion: the full content available in a SimpleXMLElement doesn't show up when using common debugging functions like `print_r` or `var_dump`, because of the way it's implemented.

If you follow [the examples in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) for how to access attributes, you will find that they are accessible:

```php
$xml = '<example><hcAmount currencyCode="USD" decimals="2">180</hcAmount></example>';
$sx = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
echo "The text content is " . (string)$sx->hcAmount
     . " and the currencyCode atttribute is " . (string)$sx->hcAmount['currencyCode'];
```

Outputs `The text content is 180 and the currencyCode atttribute is USD`

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this should do it:

```
$str = <<<XML
<hcAmount currencyCode="USD" decimals="2">180</hcAmount>
XML;
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
$currency = $doc->xpath('//hcAmount/@currencyCode');
echo $currency[0]
```

output:

```
USD
```